# How to draw 3D surface from function

Tags: matlab, 3d, geometry-surface

I am a newbie to Matlab and have a problem drawing the surface of the following inequality

```
Calc.S0Func(2.7,1,1,sigmaL)-Calc.S0Func(c,delta,xT,sigmaH)>0
```

Where Calc is a Class and S0Func(c,delta,xT,sigma) is a function with 3 unknowns (c, delta, xT)

Hope this is enough info. The S0Function is a big function which is why I have not posted it here.

Any help is very welcome

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the surface of an inequality is supposed to be; are you by chance looking for `isosurface`?

```
[c, delta, xT] = meshgrid(-2:.1:2, -2:.1:2, -2:.1:2);
values = c.^4 + delta.^4 + xT.^2.*sin(xT);
patch(isosurface(c, delta, xT, values, 1), 'FaceColor', 'red')
view(3)
```